# querying a mongoose schema with multiple relations levels

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let's suppose I've got the following Schema, it is a simple schema of a user that has a list of friends:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:           { type: String, required: true },
    friends:        [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'} ]
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I know I can do the following to query Users and even query the friends of a certain user:

```
User
    .find({name: 'fooUser'}
    .populate('friends')
    .exec(function(error, result) {
      //do something...
    });
```

I'm currently struggeling with the task of querying the friends relation up to a arbitrary "depth" e.g. the friends of the friends of user 'fooUser'.

This question relates also to any kind of relational querying of more than one relation level (with arbitrary models involved).

Do you have any hint for me on where to go with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User
    .find({name: 'fooUser'}
    .populate('friends')
    .exec(function(error, result) {
     User.populate(result,{path:"friends.friendsoffriend",model:'friendsoffriend'},function(err,result){
     //this way you can go deep and deeper

})
    });
```

https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#added-documentpopulatedpath